# update query in hibernate using NamedQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, named-query

Learning `Hibernate`.Not sure if this is a right question...

I am trying to use `NamedQuery` for `Update` in my table

```
mysql> select * from hib1;
+----+--------+---------+
| id | name   | surname |
+----+--------+---------+
|  1 | jack   | NULL    |
|  2 | rose   | NULL    |
|  3 | mathew | NULL    |
|  4 | jack   | NULL    |
|  5 | rose   | NULL    |
|  6 | Harold | kumar   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

**Main program**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SessionFactory sessFact = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessFact.openSession();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        Employee emp = new Employee();

        Query updateQ = session.getNamedQuery("UpdateSurnameOfName");

        updateQ.setParameter("name","jack");
        updateQ.setParameter("surname","dawson");

        session.save(emp);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        Iterator itr = list.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Employee e = (Employee)itr.next();
            System.out.println("Name is : "+e.getName());
        }
        sessFact.close();

    }
```

**Employee.java**

```
package hibernate_tut_emp;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;



@Entity
@Table(name="hib1")

@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="GetDetailsByName" , query="select id from Employee emp where emp.name=:name"),
    @NamedQuery(name="FindCountOfNames", query="select count(1) as cnt from Employee emp where emp.name=:name"),
    @NamedQuery(name="UpdateSurnameOfName",query="update Employee emp set emp.surname=:surname where emp.name=:name")
})
public class Employee {
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="id")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    private String surname;



    @Id 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name") 
    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(String empName) {
            this.name = empName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }


    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }


}
```

**Problem :**

But for some reason instead of `update`ng, its trying to `insert` a fresh row.Can some one please tell me the correct way of updating through `NamedQuery`

---

**Console log**

```
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate]
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:44 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: hibernate.hib1
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, name, surname]
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:45 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
Hibernate: insert into hib1 (name, surname, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Column 'name' cannot be null
Oct 02, 2014 8:57:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at hibernate_tut_emp.CreateData.main(CreateData.java:28)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'name' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 13 more
```

**Side Question :** I saw lots of suggestion of using `Session.createSQLQuery(String queryString)` ...is there any advantage of using this over `NamedQuery` for `Update`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have to do create new employee and do `session.save(emp)` for an update.
you just have to do:

`updateQ .executeUpdate();`

Comment: first time SO made me wait 5hrs for an answers...thanks fella! :)

Comment: Was it a kind of appreciation? Even some of my questions never got any answer yet!